# How to do multidimensional array processing in javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, browser, tensor, onnx

What is the way for working with multi dimensional arrays in javacsript? If i have 3d tensor stored as a Float32Array, how to best compute the max and argmax on a given axis? I'm looking for something like numpy for the browser.

I have an output of RTMPose model running on onnx runtime web. The output is a Float32array under the hood and has a shape of (1,17,512). Next I would like to process the output by getting the maximum values and indices of max values along the last axis so i get 17 maximums. Basically i want to implement [this function in javascript](https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmpose/blob/537bd8e543ab463fb55120d5caaa1ae22d6aaf06/mmpose/codecs/utils/post_processing.py#L41).

I tried using [numjs](https://github.com/grimmer0125/numjs) but it seems like the max function only computes one max and does not have any parameters. And the get function works for only retrieving a single element.

example code, taken from https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime-nextjs-template:

```js
    import * as ort from "onnxruntime-web";
    import * as img from "$lib/utils/imageHelper";
    import nj from "@d4c/numjs/build/module/numjs.min.js";
            const session = await ort.InferenceSession.create("rtmpose.onnx", {
                executionProviders: ["wasm"],
            });

            const data = await img.getImageTensorFromPath(
                "https://i.imgur.com/CzXTtJV.jpg", // image url,
                [1, 3, 256, 192]
            );
            
            // prepare feeds. use model input names as keys.
            const feeds = { input: data };

            // feed inputs and run
            const results = await session.run(feeds);
            const output = results[session.outputNames[0]];

            // output.dims is [1,17,512]
            let arr = nj.array(output.data).reshape(output.dims);
            
            // only returns one maximum
            let maxes = arr.max(2);

            // returns undefined
            arr.get(0,0)
```